# Django don't want to include the whole template in the HttpResponse

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I got a view function like this:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader

from .models import Recipe


def index(request):
    recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template('recipes/index.html')
    c = Context({'object_list': recipes})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

But because I want to implement some AJAX I don't want to include the whole rendered template in the HttpResponse object but only the required data needed to be passed to the AJAX success function.

My question is: How to make my view function to return only the ajax needed data in the response, without the need to include the whole template (as it is right now)

Comment: Does the ajax response need to return html or another format like xml/json?

Comment: In order to look for simplicity, I just would like to pass the data required for the AJAX success response in whatever the format it will be. I don't want to pass the entire html template and after look for the required data, I don't think that is the most suitable way

Comment: What format does the "required data" need to be in, html or xml/json? The solution depends on this answer.

Comment: I would ambition to use any format, but if that is not possible I guess I would use json. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send json response.You can do this.

```
from django.core import serializers


def index(request):
    recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', recipes)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: In this case, which html template is going to load the view?

Comment: It returns the json response to your ajax call.